# Local directory listings disabled seem to be disabled in Firefox

Tags: networking

I want to open  some files in a browser tab in Firefox.

When I access a path like `C:\Folder` I get "Problem Loading Page" when my permissions are all good. I can access

```
C:\Folder\image.png
C:\Folder\text_file.txt
C:\Folder\*
```

It says:

> “Access to the file was denied
>
> It may have been removed, moved, or file permissions may be preventing access.”

Is there a setting to change this or an option in about:config?

Comment: Try this file:///C:/Folder/image.png

Comment: I can access the file directly. but I need it to display the directory listing like it did in older versions..

Comment: Thanks Martin for removing the invalid tags. It used the tags from last time I asked a question and I didn't realize, I had to remove and change the subject and body of the ask question form too because it had the text from my last question  https://superuser.com/questions/1525875/does-kitty-still-support-background-image-for-terminal

Comment: Then simply try typing the name of the folder only (it works like an ftp site only it is your computer.  __file:///C:/Folder__  It should just enter into the folder which should give you a listing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to have a practice of mounting `C:\Files` to it's own drive letter by sharing the folder and mapping a network drive to `\\localhost\Files`

Technically the files are on my local system, but since they were being accessed via a drive letter mapped to a network drive (even on localhost) Firefox treated the paths on that drive letter as if they were network paths.